# Swift - Shuffling a filtered array of structs doesn't change originating array

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, shuffle

I'm writing a card game with a number of cards collected together in one array.

The data structure of the cards is the same, but the data is different.

Note: My shuffle does work.

I'm wanting to filter this array, and only shuffle the cards I have filtered.

However, whilst I can shuffle the cards, I've noticed that my originating array of cards does not change at all.

I believe that this issue is caused because my card model is a struct and not a class.

More background info.

Whilst the data for each card is different, the structure is exactly the same; both types have a name, and a numeric value.

This is modelled thusly;

```
enum FSCardType: Int {
    case property
    case anotherType
    case yetAnotherType
}

// Card Model
struct FSCard {
    let type: FSCardType
    let name: String
    let value: Int

    var description: String {
        return ("Name: \(self.name) Value: \(self.value), Type: \(self.type)")
    }
}
```

I create my cards in a static function like this:

```
class FSCardAPI: NSObject {

    public static func createCards() -> [FSCard] {
        var cards:[FSCard] = [FSCard]()
        let properties:[FSCard] = FSCardAPI.createProperties()

        cards.append(contentsOf: properties)

        return cards
    }

    public static func shuffleCards(cards:[FSCard]) -> [FSCard] {
        let shuffled:[FSCard] = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: cards) as! [FSCard]
        return shuffled
    }

    fileprivate static func createProperties() -> [FSCard] {
        var properties:[FSCard] = [FSCard]()
        for idx in 1...30 {
            let property:FSCard = FSCard(type: .property, name: "Property #\(idx)", value: idx, owner: nil)
            properties.append(property)
        }
        return properties
    }
}
```

Okay, so now I *only* want to shuffle my property cards within this cards array.

So in my `XCTest` file first filter all cards that are of type: `property`

```
func testShuffleProperties() {
        var propertyCards  = gameModel.cards.filter { (fs:FSCard) -> Bool in
            return (fs.type == .property)
        }

        propertyCards = FSCardAPI.shuffleCards(cards: propertyCards)

        print(propertyCards)
        print(" ---- ")
        print(gameModel.cards)       
}
```

This calls:

```
// Inside my FSCardAPI 
public static func shuffleCards(cards:[FSCard]) -> [FSCard] {
    let shuffled:[FSCard] = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: cards) as! [FSCard]
    return shuffled
}
```

**The issue:**

When I run my XCTest, I notice that whilst the `propertyCards` is shuffled, my `gameModel.cards` are not shuffled;

```
Test Case 'testShuffleProperties' started.

// contents of `propertyCards`
[FSCard(type: FSCardType.property, name: "Property #4", value: 4, owner: nil), 
FSCard(type: FSCardType.property, name: "Property #16", value: 16, owner: nil), 
// .. etc

// contents of `gameModel.cards`
[FSCard(type: FSCardType.property, name: "Property #1", value: 1, owner: nil), 
FSCard(type: FSCardType.property, name: "Property #2", value: 2, owner: nil), 
// .. etc
```

*Summary*

- I have an array of cards (ie: 30 cards)
- Cards are separated by types (ie: property)
- I want to filter the property cards and shuffle those cards only
- I want the original array to reflect these changes

In my test, the array gets shuffled; but the original array remains the same.

One way I can think of is that I do all the shuffling, and then sort the array by card types and then update the gameModel.cards, but that seems a bit over the top.

Another obvious way I can think about solving this is to change my `struct` to a `class` or; perhaps I need another layer in between the struct?

So my query is:

How do I filter an array of structs, only shuffle those results and change the state of the originating array?

Many thanks

---

Edit:

The properties array is the only item to shuffle.

If I add another array to the list it should not shuffle the entire contents.

IE; if I do this:

```
public static func createCards() -> [FSCard] {
        var cards:[FSCard] = [FSCard]()
        let properties:[FSCard] = FSCardAPI.createProperties()
        let cheqs:[FSCard] = FSCardAPI.createCheques()

        cards.append(contentsOf: properties)
        cards.append(contentsOf: cheqs)

        return cards
    }
```

I should only shuffle the property cards within themselves without impacting the cheqs.

I guess I could make it easier and just have 2 arrays, but at the same time I think there is no reason to do this because the data structure is the same.

Comment: please show code for `FSCardAPI.createCards()`. in FSGameModel where are you calling shuffle?

Comment: I've added the createCards() bit now

Comment: I've attempted to use class instead of a struct for my card model but the result is the same; I believe its because I never change contents of the `gameModel.cards` -- ideally I'd like to filter these cards, shuffle them and update this cards array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning to gameModel.cards and not actually changing the array. so I would not expect gameModel.cards to be shuffled.

You should either just assign the shuffled array back to gameModel.cards like so:

```
func testShuffleProperties() {
    var propertyCards  = gameModel.cards.filter { (fs:FSCard) -> Bool in
        return (fs.type == .property)
    }

    propertyCards = FSCardAPI.shuffleCards(cards: propertyCards)
    gameModel.cards = propertyCards

    print(propertyCards)
    print(" ---- ")
    print(gameModel.cards)       
}
```

Or if you want to mutate the array directly you should look at passing the cards by reference, or in Swift.. using an inout parameter. An inout parameter passes the value to the function by reference, or passed the memory addres of the value, so that it can be modified directly. Check the shuffle cards function below (how it is defined and used)

(I replaced the shuffle function with a swift extension for ease of use in a playground)

```
extension MutableCollection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {
    /// Shuffles the contents of this collection.
    mutating func shuffle() {
        let c = count
        guard c > 1 else { return }

        for (firstUnshuffled , unshuffledCount) in zip(indices, stride(from: c, to: 1, by: -1)) {
            let d: IndexDistance = numericCast(arc4random_uniform(numericCast(unshuffledCount)))
            guard d != 0 else { continue }
            let i = index(firstUnshuffled, offsetBy: d)
            swap(&self[firstUnshuffled], &self[i])
        }
    }
}

extension Sequence {
    /// Returns an array with the contents of this sequence, shuffled.
    func shuffled() -> [Iterator.Element] {
        var result = Array(self)
        result.shuffle()
        return result
    }
}

enum FSCardType: Int {
    case property
    case anotherType
    case yetAnotherType
}

// Card Model
struct FSCard {
    let type: FSCardType
    let name: String
    let value: Int

    var description: String {
        return ("Name: \(self.name) Value: \(self.value), Type: \(self.type)")
    }
}

class FSCardAPI: NSObject {

    public static func createCards() -> [FSCard] {
        var cards:[FSCard] = [FSCard]()
        let properties:[FSCard] = FSCardAPI.createProperties()

        cards.append(contentsOf: properties)

        return cards
    }

    public static func shuffleCards(cards:inout [FSCard]) {
        cards = cards.shuffled()
    }

    fileprivate static func createProperties() -> [FSCard] {
        var properties:[FSCard] = [FSCard]()
        for idx in 1...30 {
            let property:FSCard = FSCard(type: .property, name: "Property #\(idx)", value: idx)
            properties.append(property)
        }
        return properties
    }
}

var cards = FSCardAPI.createCards()

FSCardAPI.shuffleCards(cards: &cards)
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Read up on inout parameters [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html) in the In-Out parameters section.

Exert from the documentation:

Function parameters are constants by default. Trying to change the value of a function parameter from within the body of that function results in a compile-time error. This means that you can’t change the value of a parameter by mistake. If you want a function to modify a parameter’s value, and you want those changes to persist after the function call has ended, define that parameter as an in-out parameter instead.

You write an in-out parameter by placing the inout keyword right before a parameter’s type. An in-out parameter has a value that is passed in to the function, is modified by the function, and is passed back out of the function to replace the original value. For a detailed discussion of the behavior of in-out parameters and associated compiler optimizations, see In-Out Parameters.

You can only pass a variable as the argument for an in-out parameter. You cannot pass a constant or a literal value as the argument, because constants and literals cannot be modified. You place an ampersand (&) directly before a variable’s name when you pass it as an argument to an in-out parameter, to indicate that it can be modified by the function.

**EDIT:** Try this updated shuffle function, pass in the whole array and see if does what you need.

```
public static func shuffleCards(cards:inout [FSCard]) {
    let propertyCards = cards.filter({ $0.type == .property })
    let indexes = propertyCards.map { Int(cards.index(of: $0)!) }
    let shuffledCards = propertyCards.shuffled()

    for (idx, val) in indexes.enumerated() {
        cards[val] = shuffledCards[idx]
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, i appreciate the help

Comment: This is good, however I notice that if I attempt to append another array to the end of the cards it will shuffle the entire contents of the array; it should only shuffle the property cards in their respective positions and keep any other cards as they are.

Comment: ah... that won't be as easy as just calling shuffle. you'd need to know the indexes that are available. let me see if I can work it out

Comment: I've added a quick edit and clarification.  The idea is that the entire array has a collection of cards.  I only want to shuffle a handful of the cards (in this case the ones marked with a `type: property`) and it should only shuffle those without impacting any other card types.

Comment: Now I come to think about it, my idea probably infers a NSOrderedSet or NSIndexedSet or some kind of positioning reference within the array.

Comment: yeah I think your right, the index is important in this. I've added some code to the end of my answer above. It takes the full array, filters it by the cards of type property, shuffles them, works out all the indexes of each of the values in the original array and replces them with the shuffled value. Should do what you need. Hold on.. it's not working as expected, debugging it now

Comment: I'll give it a go -- I dunno, perhaps I just overcomplicating it just for the sake of being "clean code" and not repeating structure.

Comment: Error `Playground execution failed: error: cards.xcplaygroundpage:51:53: error: cannot invoke 'index' with an argument list of type '(of: (FSCard))'
        let indexes = propertyCards.map { Int(cards.index(of: $0)!) }`

Comment: Further error `cards.xcplaygroundpage:51:53: note: expected an argument list of type '(of: Self.Iterator.Element)'
        let indexes = propertyCards.map { Int(cards.index(of: $0)!) }`
                                                    ^

Comment: Oh sorry it needs to be equatable, I've left my laptop now and in the bar. Func ==(left: FSCard, right: FSCard) -> Bool { return left.type == right.type && left.value == right.value } add the other property too

Comment: I added the `static func ==(left: FSCard, right: FSCard) -> Bool {
        return left.type == right.type && left.value == right.value
    }`  but which property are you referring to?   I get an error saying: `member operator '==' must have at least one argument of type 'FSCardAPI'
    private static func ==(left: FSCard, right: FSCard) -> Bool {`

Comment: It's not a static func, also add equatable to struct definition. Struct FSCard: Equatable. I'll update my answer with working code when I get home

Comment: The complier was complaining it had to be made a static function; but I appreciate your help on this.  Thanks again

Comment: I fixed it now.  `struct FSCard: Equatable {`   and then I added  `static func ==(lhs: FSCard, rhs: FSCard) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.type == rhs.type && lhs.value == rhs.value)
    }`   at the end of my struct  -- it was complaining that I had to make it static; the log output shows me that the property cards are shuffled and other cards are not.  This is fine and will accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after you shuffle your property cards, you are not doing anything with them. You should replace property cards in your original card list with the ones in your shuffled property card list.

```
var propertyCardsShuffledOriginalArray = originalArray.map {

    var card = $0

    if $0.type == .property {
        card = shuffledPropertyCards.first as! FSCard
        shuffledPropertyCards.removeFirst()
    }

    return card
}
```

`propertyCardsShuffledOriginalArray` is what you need

Comment: I tried putting this into my playground file but it sadly complains of unresolved identifier 'propertyCardsShuffledOriginalArray.  I am not sure why I need to be removing cards.  Walk through the array creating a temporary array of all items?

Comment: 'propertyCardsShuffledOriginalArray' is just a variable name. You should set this to your 'gameModel.cards'